how can we run multiple commands in docker healthcheck (docker-compose.yml)?
how can we run multiple commands (curl and CMD ) in docker healthcheck (in test)?
here  i want to add healthchk.sh (path: /usr/healthchk.sh) also along with curl.
healthcheck:
interval: 1m
retries: 5
start_period: 5m
curl https://url:8888/abc/login.jsp || exit 1
timeout: 15s
expected result is:: curl and .sh file also should run for below. so how to add /usr/healthchk.sh for this
test: curl https://url:8888/abc/login.jsp || exit 1

Or, in so many words, the same way you run two commands anywhere else. sh -c 'first && second or put them in a script file and run that.

i tried like this, but its not working.
healthcheck:
test: curl https://url:8888/abc/login.jsp || exit 1  &&  ["CMD", "/usr/healthchk.sh"]
interval: 1m
timeout: 30s
retries: 5

No no no, you want healthcheck: test: sh -c 'curl https://url:8888/abc/login.jsp && /usr/healthchk.sh' or simply write a new script which contains both commands.

yes @tripleee, exactly i need like that only, i tried but its not working.

What you say you tried had several syntax errors so obviously that didn't work. My comment shows how to fix those errors.
